# Python: What does "foo() for i in range(bar)" mean?

Tags: python

What exactly does the following statement mean in Python?

```
randrange(10**10) for i in range(100)
```

I'm aware that `randrange` is a random number generator but cant really make out the effect of the statement.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The way you posted it, it's a [`SyntaxError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError).
But I guess the statement is inside `[]`. Then it's a [**list comprehension**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which creates a list containing 100 random numbers. It is equivalent to this code:

```
whatever = []
for i in range(100):
    whatever.append(randrange(10**10))
```

If the code was inside `()` instead of `[]` it would be a [**generator expression**](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), i.e. an iterable whose items are not created immediately but on demand.

Answer (score 25):

On its own, it would be a syntax error. Enclosed in parentheses, it's a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
(randrange(10**10) for i in range(100))
```

returns a generator that will yield the results of 100 calls to `randrange(10**10)`, one at a time.

Inside square brackets, it's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[randrange(10**10) for i in range(100)]
```

returns a list of 100 numbers resulting from a call to `randrange(10**10)` each.

The advantage of a generator expression over a list comprehension is that it's evaluated lazily, so you don't have to construct and keep the entire list in memory (which is especially relevant with very large, possibly infinite generators).